# GO, Map keys are being all updated

Tags: dictionary, go, multidimensional-array, hashmap

Is there something wrong in what I'm doing? I don't understand why the all the map keys are being updated, it should be only the 'ether' key.

```
data := []byte(`
    [{".id":"*1","actual-mtu":"1500","default-name":"ether1","disabled":"false","l2mtu":"1514","type":"ether"},{".id":"*2","actual-mtu":"1500","default-name":"bridge2","disabled":"false","l2mtu":"1514","type":"bridge"}] 
`)

var dst []map[string]string
json.Unmarshal(data, &dst)

rxTx := map[string]int{"rx": 0, "tx": 0}
typeMap := map[string]map[string]int{"wlan": rxTx, "ether": rxTx, "bridge": rxTx, "wg": rxTx}

fmt.Println(typeMap)

for _, v := range dst {

    if v["type"] == "ether" {

        typeMap["ether"]["rx"] += 1

        typeMap["ether"]["tx"] += 1
    }
}

fmt.Println(typeMap)
```

[Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/qs7_ZpI8l0o)

Output would be
`map[bridge:map[rx:1 tx:1] ether:map[rx:1 tx:1] wg:map[rx:1 tx:1] wlan:map[rx:1 tx:1]]`

But i'm expecting
`map[bridge:map[rx:0 tx:0] ether:map[rx:1 tx:1] wg:map[rx:0 tx:0] wlan:map[rx:0 tx:0]]`

Comment: In the end i understood the cause for this, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because maps are actually like pointers
and all "wlan" , "ether" , bridge" and "wg" keys are pointing to the same value(rxTx).
there are many ways to achieve what you want but here is a quick fix:

```
data := []byte(`
    [{".id":"*1","actual-mtu":"1500","default-name":"ether1","disabled":"false","l2mtu":"1514","type":"ether"},{".id":"*2","actual-mtu":"1500","default-name":"bridge2","disabled":"false","l2mtu":"1514","type":"bridge"}] 
`)

    var dst []map[string]string
    json.Unmarshal(data, &dst)

    rxTxWlan := map[string]int{"rx": 0, "tx": 0}
    rxTxEther := map[string]int{"rx": 0, "tx": 0}
    rxTxBridge := map[string]int{"rx": 0, "tx": 0}
    rxTxWg := map[string]int{"rx": 0, "tx": 0}

    typeMap := map[string]map[string]int{"wlan": rxTxWlan, "ether": rxTxEther, "bridge": rxTxBridge, "wg": rxTxWg}

    fmt.Println(typeMap)

    for _, v := range dst {

        if v["type"] == "ether" {
            typeMap["ether"]["rx"] += 1

            typeMap["ether"]["tx"] += 1
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(typeMap)
```